Issues parsing the ephemeral key response following protocol
In my iOS App, I have had stripe integrated with sk_test and now, I am trying to use sk_live. I have configured my live key in my .env, index.js, runtimeconfig.json and remoteconfig.json. When I try to run, my app crashes with the error message,

Assertion failed: Could not parse the ephemeral key response following protocol STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider. Make sure your backend is sending the unmodified JSON of the ephemeral key to your app. For more info, see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#prepare-your-api

So looking at my stripe logs, I am seeing

resource_missing - customer
No such customer: 'cus_...'; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.

This led me to realize a lot of customers were in test mode. So, I deleted all of the customers info from test mode, and deployed a function that will convert their accounts to live mode.
Below is how I create a stripe customer when they sign up for my app.
   exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    console.log('started');
  return await stripe.customers.create({
    email: user.email,
  }).then(async (customer) => {
    console.log('user stripe account id ----------->' + customer.id);
    return await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: 'express',
      country: 'US',
      email: user.email,
      capabilities: {
        card_payments: {requested: true},
        transfers: {requested: true}
      },
    }).then(async (connectedAccount) => {
      console.log('user connected account id ----------->' + connectedAccount.id);
      const data = {
        customer_id: customer.id,
        connected_account_id: connectedAccount.id
      };
      return await admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${user.uid}`).set(data)
      .then(async (result) => {
        return result;
      });
    });
  });
});

Below is the function that I am attempting to use to convert all previous test accounts to live accounts.
    exports.createStripeCustomerIfDeleted = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    // Check if the user is authenticated
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'User is not authenticated');
    }

    // Check if the user already has a Stripe customer ID
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.auth.uid}`).once('value');
    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
      console.log('User does not have a Stripe customer ID');
      return { success: true, message: 'User does not have a Stripe customer ID' };
    }

    // Check if the Stripe customer already exists in Stripe
    const stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.list({ email: context.auth.token.email });
    if (stripeCustomer.data.length > 0) {
      console.log('Stripe customer already exists in Stripe');
      return { success: true, message: 'Stripe customer already exists in Stripe' };
    }

    // Delete the corresponding entry from Firebase
    await admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.auth.uid}`).remove();
    console.log('Firebase entry deleted');

    // Create a new Stripe customer
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email: context.auth.token.email,
    });

    // Create a new Stripe connected account
    const connectedAccount = await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: 'express',
      country: 'US',
      email: context.auth.token.email,
      capabilities: {
        card_payments: { requested: true },
        transfers: { requested: true }
      },
    });

    // Save the Stripe customer ID and connected account ID to the database
    const newData = {
      customer_id: customer.id,
      connected_account_id: connectedAccount.id
    };
    await admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.auth.uid}`).set(newData);

    console.log('Stripe customer created successfully');
    return { success: true, message: 'Stripe customer created successfully' };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating Stripe customer:', error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Error creating Stripe customer', error);
  }
});

What this is aiming to achieve is

Checking to see if account is authenticated (Which it should be)
Checking to see if there is data under stripe_customers referring to the current users UID. (Which there is because this information is created once the users create an account)
Then checks to see if there is matching information in stripe for the current user. If there is, do nothing. If there isn't, step 4.
Delete all information associated with the UID under stripe_customers in firebase.
recreate and save stripe customerId and connectedAccountId to firebase and stripe.
be happy.

Also, I am calling this function in my app delegate after confirming that the user is authenticated.
    func createStripeCustomerIfDeleted(for userId: String) {
    // Call the Firebase Callable Cloud Function to create a Stripe customer
    Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeCustomerIfDeleted").call(["userId": userId]) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print("Error triggering createStripeCustomerIfDeleted: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            // Handle error
        } else if let data = result?.data as? [String: Any] {
            if let success = data["success"] as? Bool, success {
                print("Stripe customer created successfully")
                // Handle success
            } else {
                print("Failed to create Stripe customer: \(data["message"] as? String ?? "Unknown error")")
                // Handle failure
            }
        }
    }
}

And when I check my function logs, I am seeing
Request received - Customer ID:
What exactly am I leaving out?
Lastly, I have recognized that this is only happening when I use sk_live. If I use sk_test with a live account this is not happening. but if I use sk_live with a test or a live account I am seeing these issues.

Most likely your backend is using a test mode API key, whereas your iOS app is using a live mode publishable key. And that's why the customer is created in test mode, which is not accessible in live mode, as per resource_missing - customer No such customer: 'cus_...'; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.
You should keep our backend API key and frontend publishable key consistent, they should be both in test mode, or live mode.

I appreciate your insight, but I am very confident that all of my test keys have been updated to live keys.
